# Parse and Swift. Set tableViewCell accessory type from Parse relation

Tags: ios, uitableview, parse-platform

So, I have got a tableView which shows courses. The user is able to set Checkmarks on these courses (cells) and save them in his PFUser object as a relation to the Courses class (where all courses are stored).
My question is, how do I checkmark the courses a user has already saved at some point before.

This is my attempt, but I don’t know how to continue. How do I get the cells with a specific Label? (Or is there a better way?)

```
    let courseRel = PFUser.currentUser()?.relationForKey("usercourses")
    let query = courseRel!.query()
    let qObjects :Array = query!.findObjects()!
    println(qObjects)
    for var qObjectsCount = qObjects.count; qObjectsCount > 0; --qObjectsCount {
        var qAnObject: AnyObject = qObjects[qObjectsCount - 1]
        var courseName = qAnObject["coursename"]
        println(courseName)
        if let cell: AnyObject? = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("courseCell"){

        }

    }
```

EDIT: that code is in my override viewDidLoad

EDIT2:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath, object: PFObject?) -> PFTableViewCell {

    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("courseCell") as! PFTableViewCell!
    if cell == nil {
        cell = PFTableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "courseCell")
    }

    let courseRel = PFUser.currentUser()?.relationForKey("usercourses")
    let query = courseRel!.query()
    let qObjects :Array = query!.findObjects()!


    // Extract values from the PFObject to display in the table cell
    if let courseName = object?["coursename"] as? String {
        cell?.textLabel?.text = courseName


        if contains(qObjects, object) {
            cell?.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.Checkmark
        }
    }

    return cell
}
```

Error in line ‚if contains(qObjects, object) {'

> Generic parameter 'S.Generator.Element’ cannot be bound to non-@objc protocol type 'AnyObject'

EDIT3:

```
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath, object: PFObject?) -> PFTableViewCell {

    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("courseCell") as! PFTableViewCell!
    if cell == nil {
        cell = PFTableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "courseCell")
    }

    let courseRel = PFUser.currentUser()?.relationForKey("usercourses")
    let query = courseRel!.query()
    let qObjects :Array = query!.findObjects()!


    // Extract values from the PFObject to display in the table cell
    if let courseName = object?["coursename"] as? String {
        cell?.textLabel?.text = courseName
        cell.tintColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    }

    if contains(qObjects, { $0 === object }) {
        cell?.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.Checkmark
        self.selectedRows.addIndex(indexPath.row)
    }else{
        cell?.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.None
    }

    return cell
}
```

EDIT4: (Working code)

In the class:

```
// Initializing qObject variable 
var qObjects :Array<AnyObject> = []
```

In my objectsDidLoad:

```
    // Get PFObjects for the checkmarks on courses the currentUser has already selected before
    let courseRel = PFUser.currentUser()?.relationForKey("usercourses")
    let query = courseRel!.query()
    qObjects = query!.findObjects()!
```

In my tableView(cellForRowAtIndexPath):

```
    // Extract values from the PFObject to display in the table cell
    if contains(qObjects, { $0 === object }) {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.Checkmark
        self.selectedRows.addIndex(indexPath.row)
    } else {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.None
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't try to search for a cell. Well, you can, but not like you're trying to - I'll come back to that.

Your current code is creating new cells, not finding existing cells, so that won't work.

What you should really be doing is storing the array of returned objects, `qObjects`, and then when you're configuring the cell for display checking if that array contains the object for the current cell. If it does, tick it, otherwise remove the tick.

Now, if the load of `qObjects` happens after the view is shown you have 2 options:

1. reload the table view
2. update just the visible items

Option 2. is obviously better, especially if the user might be scrolling the list. To do that you want to use the array returned by calling `indexPathsForVisibleRows` on the table view. Then, iterate that list, get the associated object and check if it's in `qObjects`, then get the cell on display with `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` and update it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Thing is, I am using the PFQueryTableViewController class, which does all the configurations for me. Any idea how I could do it in that class? I know, I can get the objects in the tableview with objects!, but I don’t know how to get the cell of the object…

Comment: same, its all by index path

Comment: Okay, so I need to use 'dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(„courseCell“, forIndexPath: indexPath)‘, right? But how do I get my index Path? I have got sections in my tableview. So 'NSIndexPath(forItem…)’, but how do I get to run it for every single row in every section? (Which I will need to do to compare them to my qObjects, right?)

Comment: no, dequeue creates a new cell, you use `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` - did you read my answer and understand the approach? you aren't trying to refresh everything, if you want to do that just reload the table

Comment: Well, not entirely. My problem still is, that I do not configure the cells in my code. The PFQueryTableViewController Class does this in the background. So, how do I get all my Cells in all my Sections to compare them to my qObjects array? (I would assume I need some kind of loop, but I would first need to find out, how many rows/section and how many sections I have got, right?)

Comment: So you should be implementing the method to update the cells instead of having the superclass do it

Comment: Do the query once, not once for every cell. Always set the accessory, to check mark or none.

Comment: Got it to work, the line has to be `if contains(qObjects, { $0 === object }) {` Scrolling is extremely slow now, any idea how to fix that?

Comment: Are you still doing the synchronous query for every cell?

Comment: Ehm, I don’t think so, moved it out of the if{}. Have a look at my Edit3.

Comment: You must move it out of that function, do it when the view is loaded or becomes visible and in the background...

Comment: How do I do that? I can’t use `object` in any other function, can I?

Comment: You store `qObjects` as an instance variable

Comment: Why qObjects? qObjects isn’t the problem. I wanted to move all of it (the three lets and the if) in my objectsDidLoad. Which gets me 'use of unresolved identifier 'object‘ '

Comment: It is, you need to get that list early and then use it when the cells are configured, you only move the data collection, the configuration stays there

Comment: Ah, okay, I’m retarded, that makes sense. But I still can’t get it to work. If I just move the three let-lines into the class, it says: ‚Class doesn’t have a member called courseRel‘, if I put it in a function and put `let qObjects :Array<AnyObject>` before that function (in my class) I get 'property self.qObjects not initialized at super.init call‘ (and if I don’t I obviously can’t use `qObjects` in another funcition) :(

Comment: Changed it to `let qObjects :[Array<AnyObject>]`, which gets rid of the error, but then I got: 'Cannot find an overload for 'contains' that accepts an argument list of type '([Array<AnyObject>], (_) -> _)‘‘. Then changed it to: `let qObjects :[Array<PFObject>]`, but get the same error. Am I not querying for PFObjects?

Comment: Okay, forget the last to comments, got it to work. Will edit the OP again in case somebody is interested in the solution.